# IntelliJ isn't running correctly

Tags: intellij-idea

Everytime when I start IntelliJ ultimate edition, I just get a black screen and the fonts are very weird and unreadable:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RN2F9.png)

I already tried to uninstall and then reinstall intellij which did not work.
Has somebody a idea for a solution?

Comment: Try to clean folders with settings/configs: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519 and run with defaults.

Comment: If I clear the file in the config-folder of intellij it does not change anything. It's then still the same and if I start it it creates a new one.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What file did you delete?